# Why does GRADLE uploads the wrong JAR file of my Grails application to MAVEN repository?

Tags: grails, gradle, jar

I haven an Grails 3.1.8 application and building an executable jar file, which runs fine. Now I wanna upload the produced jar file to my maven repository by using the gradle **maven plugin**. Here the problem begins. The upload tasks uploads the wrong JAR file.

If I execute 'grails assemble' two files get produced:

```
100032 mcc-1.0.9.jar
4880 mcc-1.0.9.jar.original
```

As you can see, the first file having the bigger size is obviously the fat jar file, which works fine. After the assemble task the 'upload' task is executed and uploads the smaller file. I tried also to define the artifact:

```
artifacts {
   archives file: file("build/libs/mcc-1.0.9.jar")
}
```

Then the fat jar get overwritten or is not produced at all:

```
4880 mcc-1.0.9.jar  
4880 mcc-1.0.9.jar.original
```

and the small JAR gets uploaded again. How can I force gradle to take the fat jar file or at least produce only the correct file?

Comment: what gradle task are you using to publish the jar? you need to show more of your build gradle, either the uploadArchives section or the publications section, depending on which publishing plugin you're using.

Comment: I'm using the maven plugin to publish the artifact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Hubert Klein who answered my question in the comment section of this article: https://dzone.com/articles/grails-goodness-creating-a-fully-executable-jar.

*This happens because the uploadArchives task depends on the jar task by default. But then the bootRepackage task is not executed, that actually overwrites the jar file with the full executable jar file. 
If you add to your build.gradle file that the task uploadArchives depends on the assemble task the bootRepackage task is invoked before uploadArchives:*

```
uploadArchives.dependsOn(assemble)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue

```
gradle clean build assemble artifactoryPublish
```